# Issues in customizing toolbar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I wanted to achieve the following task

- Remove the default toolbar
- Build a custom toolbar
- change the default title, title text color, title text alignment in the toolbar

I successfully removed the default toolbar but while building the custom toolbar I'm not able to

- Change the title text color
- Change the titleText alignment

I tried  out the existing solutions provided to the above problems at stack overflow but nothing seemed to be helpful in my case

Here's toolBar.xml file

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/toolbarC"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

android:theme="@style/Mystyle"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:titleTextColor="#ffffff">


</android.support.v7.widget.toolbar>
```

Here is my main xml file

```
enter code here`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:layout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#3dcc24">

<include
layout="@layout/clubs_tool_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's is my styles.xml file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="ColorTemp">@color/ColorTemp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="Mystyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name = "android:textSize">30sp</item>



</style>
</resources>
```

[image]

This is what my screen looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to address the appropriate class so use [`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarC"

    app:title="YourTitle"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"    
    android:theme="@style/Mystyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"/>
```

instead of

```
android.support.v7.widget.toolbar
```

Comment: I made the required changes. Now the toolbar is empty, how do I add a title?

Comment: you have to use the title attribute ` app:title="yourTitle"`

Comment: I got it ! Problem solved ! Thank you so much for the help !

Comment: you can further add your own textView inside toolbar instead of `app:title` to further manipulate it if you want , i am glad that i could help , happy coding